# Extra inter-line spacing in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing

I have a table that is typeset using a `tabular` environment.  (I want to keep it in a `tabular` environment.)  The contents of each row is an expression involving radicals. The inter-line spacing is inconsistent with other tables in my file and with the inter-line spacing of the text in my file.  I seem to recall that the inter-line spacing should be `1.2` times the height of the current line or current row.  Is that right?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\textbf{Example}} \vskip1.25mm
The following functions are increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$. \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{tabular}{r l}
i.)     &       \hspace*{-0.5em}$x^{2} + x$ \\
ii.)    &       \hspace*{-0.5em}$x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7$ \\
iii.)   &       \hspace*{-0.5em}$x^{2} + \sqrt{x}$
\end{tabular}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent {\textbf{Example}} \vskip1.25mm
The following functions are increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$. \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{tabular}{r l}
i.)     &       \hspace*{-0.5em}$\sqrt{x^{2} + x}$ \\
ii.)    &       \hspace*{-0.5em}$\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7}$ \\
iii.)   &       \hspace*{-0.5em}$(x^{2} + \sqrt{x}){\vphantom{x^{2} + \sqrt{x}}}^{3}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you using tabular here, when it is clearly a list? (but `\\[2cm]` will add extra space).

Comment: @David Carlisle  First, I would like to know the command or option to get such a specification.  Second, I don't want to bother to edit all the other `tabular` environments in my file.

Comment: @David Carlisle  Instead of `[2cm]`, I would like to specify `1.2` times the height of `\sqrt[3]{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7}`.  Can you tell me the code for that?

Comment: @Werner  How about a link to the other post?

Comment: @Adelyn: "...the other post"? What other post?

Comment: @Werner  I didn't see the link to "the other post."

Comment: @Werner Isn't there an option like "\\ [1.2*\baselineskip]" that can be placed after a row in a `tabular` environment?  If all rows in a `tabular` environment contain entries such as `$x^{2} + x$`, I may not want to include any extra vertical spacing.  If a row contains  `$x^{2} + \sqrt{x}$` or  `$\sqrt[3]{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7}$` or `$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$`, I think that I would want a line skip that is something like `1.2` times the height of the box containing the contents of the current row.  (I read that on a different post some time ago.)

Comment: @Adelyn: Yes, for individual rows you can use a `\\[<len>]` row ending that would insert a vertical gap of length `<len>`. Using `\\[1.2\baselineskip]` is sufficient (no need for a multiplication `*` sign).

Comment: @Werner I used \\[1.2\baselineskip] and \\[2\baselineskip] after the first two rows in the second tabular environment. There was no change. Do I need a package loaded for these to be interpreted. (I did not get an error.)

Comment: @Adelyn: Inside a tabular you would need \normalbaselineskip, not \baselineskip.

Comment: @Werner  If the contents of the first row were also contained in a bigger box, as in `\sqrt[3]{x^{3}  + 1}`$ or in `\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}`, how would I get similar inter-line spacing between the text preceding the `tabular` environment and the first row of  the `tabular` environment?

Comment: @Adelyn: You should ask a new question with that specific details in mind.

Comment: @Werner  Please see my post at `Extra inter-line spacing in a tabular environment (Version 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

With code below I was obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
    \usepackage{array}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\noindent {\textbf{Example}} 

The following functions are increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$. 

\begin{tabular}{r @{\ } >{$}l<{$}}
i.)     &       x^{2} + x \\
ii.)    &       x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7 \\
iii.)   &       x^{2} + \sqrt{x}
\end{tabular}

\vskip0.25in
\noindent {\textbf{Example}} \vskip1.25mm
The following functions are increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$. \vskip1.25mm

    \begin{tabular}{r @{\ } >{$}l<{$}}
i.)     &       \sqrt{x^{2} + x} \\
ii.)    &       \sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7} \\
iii.)   &       \bigl(x^{2} + \sqrt{x}\bigr)^{3}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I simplify your MWE with goal to obtain more compact code. For distance between rows I use `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`.

**Edit:**
If you like to increase distances between tavle rows, you can do this on two ways:

- by terminating table row by `\\[<additional space>]` (used in the first example below) as mentioned David Carlisle in his comment
- by help of macro `\addlinespace` from package `booktabs` (used in second example) which add (about) 3pt additional space between rows.

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\noindent {\textbf{Example}}

The following functions are increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$.

\medskip
    \begin{tabular}{r @{\ } >{$}l<{$}}
i.)     &       x^{2} + x \\
ii.)    &       x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7 \\[8pt]
iii.)   &       x^{2} + \sqrt{x}
    \end{tabular}

\vskip0.25in
\noindent {\textbf{Example}} \vskip1.25mm
The following functions are increasing on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$. 

\medskip
    \begin{tabular}{r @{\ } >{$}l<{$}}
i.)     &       \sqrt{x^{2} + x} \\
ii.)    &       \sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7} \\
    \addlinespace
iii.)   &       \bigl(x^{2} + \sqrt{x}\bigr)^{3}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What is better to use? Difficult to say. I usual use `\addlinespace`.

[image]

Comment: I prefer your edit using `@{\ }`.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `array` package.  What does `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` in the preamble do?  Does it make the inter-line spacing in a `tabular` environment `1.5` times more than the inter-line spacing for text in `text` mode?

Comment: I am inclined to keep the inter-line spacing in the first example the same as it is `text` mode.  In the second example "`1.5 times" or "`1.2` times" looks right.  How can I increase the inter-line spacing for only certain lines in a `tabular` environment?  For example, maybe I would have `$\displaystyle{\frac{1 - \sqrt{x}}{1 + \sqrt{x}}}$` in one of the rows.

Comment: With either `array` or `booktabs` package, can you make the inter-line spacing "`1.2` * height of box containing `\sqrt[3]{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 3x - 7}`"?

Comment: The package array is used for change column into math environment: `>{$}l<{$}` (for details read documentation of it), meanwhile `booktabs` offers rules like `toprule`, `midrule`, ... and `addlinespace`, which is intended for sets "professional" looks of tables (for details read its documentation). Both ``\\`` and `\addlinespace` actually doesn't make higher box but increases distance between rows for given amount.

Comment: Werner informed me that `\\[1.2\baselineskip]` should give me the spacing that I requested.  For me, nothing happens.  Can you show me code that keeps the inter-line spacing of text in the first example but gives me the spacing that I want using `\\[1.2\baselineskip]` after the first two rows of the second example.  (So, you will have to remove `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` from your preamble.)

Comment: @Adelyn, your question is marked as duplicate. This means, that already has answer on SE (just follow given link). If it not solve your problem, please ask new question. Since mine is not satisfactory to you (as you will se, it propose similar solution as are given on the link),  I will erase it soon.