# Tabular ignoring optional parameter to \\

Tags: tables, spacing, optional-arguments

In a basic `tabular` environment it seems that the optional parameter to `\\` sometime has no effect. For instance, why is there no additional vertical spacing following the highlighted lines even though each line ends with a `\\[2.0ex]`?

[image]

### Notes:

- I am aware of solutions that apply to *all* lines in the table:

  - `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`
  - `\extrarowheight=3pt\relax` (With the `array` package)

but am specifically looking for a solution where I can control the
spacing on a line by line basis as per the MWE.

### References

- [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/4301)
- [Extra inter-line spacing in a tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295937/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% --------------------- These two for \rowcolor (to reproduce image)
%\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}%  For \extrarowheight

\newcommand{\ShortText}{Short text.}% Fits on one line
\newcommand{\LongText}{Long text that takes up more than one line.}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% This works, but applies to ALL rows
%\extrarowheight=3pt\relax% This works with the array package, but applies to ALL rows
\begin{tabular}{l p{0.35\linewidth} p{0.45\linewidth}}
    Num & Column 1   & Column 2   \\[2.0ex]
     1  & \ShortText & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]
     2  & \ShortText & \LongText  \\[2.0ex]
     %\rowcolor{red!25}% <-- Needs "colortbl" and "xcolor"
     3  & \LongText  & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]% <--- Why this optional parameter ignored
     4  & \LongText  & \LongText  \\[2.0ex]
     5  & \ShortText & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. Looks like I had this issue before: [Vertical Spacing in Tabular with bmatrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180099/4301) and I just need to increase the space as the optional parameter is the _minimum_ height of the row, not the excess space to insert following the row.

Comment: I get a [different output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUIkW.png) - more sensible when thinking about ``\\[<len>]`` when I don't colour the `tabular`.

Comment: @Werner: Yeah, good point. Still has an issue on one row, which based on my above comment, I just need to increase the amount.

Comment: You can use `\noalign{\vspace{2.0ex}}`.

Comment: Colouring aside, the value is added to the final column entry. If previous columns have larger vertical content, using ``\\[<len>]`` will only show if `<len>` exceeds this vertical difference.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yeah I saw that _hack_ at [Vertical Spacing in Tabular with bmatrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180103/4301), but I think Heiko's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @Werner while in tl17 it makes a difference if the longer text is in the last column or not, this is no longer true with a current array.sty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I've running TeX Live 2018 with `array v2.4h` and getting some spaces, but not all of them. So I don't know what you mean by "this is no longer true with a current `array.sty`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Heiko doesn't mention it below but  the reason that booktabs can add a "natural" length and the reason the standard argument is implemented the way it is is due to vertical lines,. booktabs famously does not support (in fact actively discourages) the use of `|` and that simplifies things greatly.

Comment: @werner `2  & \ShortText & \LongText  \\[2.0ex]` gives a different result with a current array.sty (no space) than with an older one (space).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You're right. I removed `array` altogether.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\\` inside a table is defined via `\@tabularcr`. If there is an optional argument with positive length, the macro takes the *default* depth of the line, adds the length and sets an invisible rule with the larger depth.

However, the problematic lines have already a much larger depth because of top-aligned two line cells. As a result, the optional argument remains ineffective unless its length is increased to become larger than the (unknown) depth of the two line cells.

Macro `\addlinespace` of package `booktabs` uses a different method by inserting the space after the row.

Example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
%% --------------------- These two for \rowcolor (to reproduce image)
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}%  For \extrarowheight
\usepackage{booktabs}% For \addlinespace, \defauladdspace

\newcommand{\ShortText}{Short text.}% Fits on one line
\newcommand{\LongText}{Long text that takes up more than one line.}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{2ex}%
\begin{tabular}{l p{0.35\linewidth} p{0.45\linewidth}}
    Num & Column 1   & Column 2   \\\addlinespace
     1  & \ShortText & \ShortText \\\addlinespace
     2  & \ShortText & \LongText  \\\addlinespace
     \rowcolor{red!25}% <-- Needs xcolor with option table
     3  & \LongText  & \ShortText \\\addlinespace
     4  & \LongText  & \LongText  \\\addlinespace
     5  & \ShortText & \ShortText \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The reason for the different implementation is that the method of LaTeX's `\@tabularcr` supports vertical rules. Macro `\addlinespace` on the other side comes from package `booktabs` for tables *without* vertical rules.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a spacing with the optional parameter works fine for one-line rows. If there are more lines in a row cell, you have to change the value.

A better solution consists in using the `\cellspacetop-bottomlimit` lengths  from package `cellspace`, which defines a *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`  (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). By definition, this spacing is added only if necessary.

*Unrelated* : if you load `xcolor` with option `[table]`, you don't have to load yourself `colortbl`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{1ex}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{1ex}
\usepackage{array}% For \extrarowheight

\newcommand{\ShortText}{Short text.}% Fits on one line
\newcommand{\LongText}{Long text that takes up more than one line.}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l S{p{0.35\linewidth}} S{p{0.45\linewidth}}}
    Num & Column 1 & Column 2 \\
     1 & \ShortText & \ShortText \\
     2 & \ShortText & \LongText \\
     3 & \LongText & \ShortText \\ % <--- Why this optional parameter ignored
     4 & \LongText & \LongText \\
     5 & \ShortText & \ShortText
\end{tabular}
\vskip1cm
\begin{tabular}{l p{0.35\linewidth} p{0.45\linewidth}}
    Num & Column 1 & Column 2 \\[2.0ex]
     1 & \ShortText & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]
     2 & \ShortText & \LongText \\[4.5ex]
     3 & \LongText & \ShortText \\[4.5ex]% <--- Why this optional parameter ignored
     4 & \LongText & \LongText \\[2.0ex]
     5 & \ShortText & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Life is much easier if you are using `tblr` environment from the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray): `\\[dimen]` **always** adds vertical space to the row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt}

\newcommand{\ShortText}{Short text.}% Fits on one line
\newcommand{\LongText}{Long text that takes up more than one line.}%

\begin{document}

\noindent
\section{Tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l p{0.35\linewidth} p{0.45\linewidth}}
\hline
    Num & Column 1   & Column 2   \\[2.0ex]
     1  & \ShortText & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]
     2  & \ShortText & \LongText  \\[2.0ex]
     \rowcolor{red!25}
     3  & \LongText  & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]% <--- this optional parameter is ignored
     4  & \LongText  & \LongText  \\[2.0ex]
     5  & \ShortText & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\section{Tabularray}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{l p{0.35\linewidth} p{0.45\linewidth}}
\hline
    Num & Column 1   & Column 2   \\[2.0ex]
     1  & \ShortText & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]
     2  & \ShortText & \LongText  \\[2.0ex]
     \SetRow{red8}
     3  & \LongText  & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]% <--- this optional parameter is not ignored
     4  & \LongText  & \LongText  \\[2.0ex]
     5  & \ShortText & \ShortText \\[2.0ex]
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks for making me of this new pacakge!  I am assuming that `\SetTblrInner` is a recent addition as that was not in my TeXLive2021 (but not recently updated).

Comment: In old version, it was `\SetTblrDefault` command.