# Diagonal line in table is out of box

Tags: tables

Why the diagonal line in the table is out of box, and how to fix it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{slashbox,pict2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Tabel $Q\cap M'$}
    \begin{tabular}{|@{}c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \backslashbox{\tabular{@{}l@{}}$Q\in\mathfrak{p}$\endtabular}{$M'\in P(A)$}
        & $\varnothing$& $\{1\}$& $\{2\}$&$\{1,2\}$\\
        \hline
        $\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$\\
        \hline
        $\{1\}$&$\varnothing$&$\{1\}$&$\varnothing$&$\{1\}$\\
        \hline\hline
        $\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$\\
        \hline
        $\{2\}$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\{2\}$&$\{2\}$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tabelksmanna}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier   
\end{document}
```

Comment: related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451964/138900

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I believe that the `slashbox` package is deprecated and is no longer part of TeXLive. Instead, use the `diagbox` package.

Second, you may fix the problem you've encountered by omitting the `@{}` particle in the argument of the `tabular` environment. I.e., replace

```
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c|c|c|c|c|}
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
```

---

More generally, you may want to re-consider your approach to displaying information in a tabular fashion.

- When I look at your table, what I see first and foremost are lots and lots of vertical and horizontal lines. It takes a non-trivial effort to start discovering what's *inside* all those little (prison) cells.
- Do think about employing a more open and inviting "look" to present the tabular material. You could begin by omitting all vertical lines and retaining only a few, but well-spaced, horizontal lines, as in done in the example shown below. (By the way, is the third data row a repeat of the first data row? If so, the third row is redundant and could be omitted, right?)

I'm pretty sure your readers will appreciate your effort -- and reward it by actually bothering to look at the *contents* of the table. Getting your readers to absorb the information you present must be seen as part of having written a successful paper, right? :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{diagbox,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % mathptmx is very old
\usepackage{booktabs} % new
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

    \caption{Tabel $Q\cap M'$}
    \label{tabelksmanna}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \backslashbox{\tabular{@{}l@{}}$Q\in\mathfrak{p}$\endtabular}{$M'\in P(A)$}
        & $\varnothing$& $\{1\}$& $\{2\}$&$\{1,2\}$\\
        \hline
        $\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$\\
        \hline
        $\{1\}$&$\varnothing$&$\{1\}$&$\varnothing$&$\{1\}$\\
        \hline\hline
        $\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$\\
        \hline
        $\{2\}$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\{2\}$&$\{2\}$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \bigskip
    \caption{Same material, rearranged}
    %% Use an 'array' env. since all contents are math-y
    $\begin{array}{@{}lcccc@{}}
        \toprule
        Q\in\mathfrak{p} & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{M'\in P(A)}\\
        \cmidrule(l){2-5}
        & \varnothing & \{1\} & \{2\} &\{1,2\} \\
        \midrule
        \varnothing&\varnothing&\varnothing&\varnothing&\varnothing\\
        \{1\} & \varnothing & \{1\} & \varnothing & \{1\} \\
        \addlinespace
        \varnothing&\varnothing&\varnothing&\varnothing&\varnothing\\
        \{2\}&\varnothing&\varnothing&\{2\}&\{2\}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{array}$

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good, that's what I want.

Comment: Third row is same with first row. But, I want displaying it twice.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which has its own built-in command `\diagbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\caption{Tabel $Q\cap M'$}
\label{tabelksmanna}
\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{22mm}cccc}[vlines]
    \Hline
    \rule{0pt}{9mm}
    \diagbox{\footnotesize $Q\in\mathfrak{p}$}{\footnotesize $M'\in P(A)$}
    & $\varnothing$& $\{1\}$& $\{2\}$&$\{1,2\}$\\
    \Hline
    $\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$\\
    \Hline
    $\{1\}$&$\varnothing$&$\{1\}$&$\varnothing$&$\{1\}$\\
    \Hline\Hline
    $\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$\\
    \Hline
    $\{2\}$&$\varnothing$&$\varnothing$&$\{2\}$&$\{2\}$\\
    \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]